# Send complex object to a web api controller with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass a complex object called vm that has one object 'Budget' and one array 'BudgetDetails' that is populated with the rows of an html table, and when i try to send this complex object to my api controller with ajax i have this error message in the console "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var vm = {
        Budget: {},
        BudgetDetails: []
    }

    $("#submit").click(function () {
            vm.Budget = {
                DateIssue: $("#dateIssue").val(),
                BudgetAccepted: $("#budgetAccepted").val(),
                VehicleId: $("#vehicleId").val()
            };

            $('#budgetDetail tr.detail').each(function (index, tr) {                   
                var lines = $('td', tr).map(function (index, td) {
                    return $(td).text();
                });
                vm.BudgetDetails.push(lines);
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/budgets",
                method: "post",
                data: vm,
                success: function () {
                    console.log("ok");
                }
            });
        });
});
```

If I put as a comment the part where you insert each row of the html table in an array does not show me any errors in the console, and sends without problem the object 'Budget' to the API. The error appears when I try to send the 'BudgetDetails' array with the 'Budget' object.

This is my API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateBudget(NewBudgetDto newBudgetDto)
{           
    return Ok();
}
```

This is my NewBudgetDto class:

```
public class NewBudgetDto
{
    public BudgetDto Budget { get; set; }
    public List<BudgetDetailDto> BudgetDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This is my BudgetDto class:

```
 public class BudgetDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateIssue { get; set; }
    public VehicleDto Vehicle{ get; set; }
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public bool BudgetAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

This is my BudgetDetailDto class:

```
public class BudgetDetailDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public byte Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

I really don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify{{ newBudgetDto: vm })` and add `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: BudgetDetailDto probly has a reference to BudgetDto, and It's recursively killing the stack when the response is trying to be deserialized. Or BudgetDto has a reference for NewBudgetDto.

Comment: i put the JSON.stringify{{ newBudgetDto: vm }) and the contentType: 'application/json'  and now is sending null values.

Answer (score 0):

When ever if you want send complex then you need to use stringfy. 
Here is demo , i hope it will work at your side.

```
            var BudgetDetailArr = [];
            var BudgetObj = {
                DateIssue: $("#dateIssue").val(),
                BudgetAccepted: $("#budgetAccepted").val(),
                VehicleId: $("#vehicleId").val()
            }

            $('#budgetDetail tr.detail').each(function (index, tr) {
                var lines = $('td', tr).map(function (index, td) {
                    return $(td).text();
                });
                BudgetDetailArr.push(lines);
            }); 
            //console here to see value of BudgetDetailArr | BudgetObj
            console.log(BudgetDetailArr)
            console.log(BudgetObj)

            var sendObj = {
                Budget: BudgetObj,   // same as model property name
                BudgetDetails: BudgetDetailArr    // same as model property name
            }

    //ajax code
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: '/api/budgets',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',  //send type of data to sever
                dataType: 'text', //retrun type of data from server
                traditional: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(sendObj),
                success: function (response, statusText, xhr) {
                 console.log(response)

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {                       
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);

                }
            });
```

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.